# Duplicate a page containing minipages

Tags: floats, page-breaking, minipage

I am beginner to the minipages environment and am having some difficulty writing on the next page after the first one, even with the usage of `\pagebreak`. If I use `\pagebreak` and paste the template (the whole document body) on the the second page, the minipages are just superimposed on the first page. I am using the document to make flashcards. Ideally, I'd like to create a bunch of flashcards for a book. But with each document only giving me 5 flashcards, I'm being forced to create a new document for a topic if I have more than 5 flashcards.

Is there any way to make sure that I can duplicate the whole document a couple of times on different pages?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[pdfusetitle]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage[icelandic, english]{babel}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[nomarkers]{endfloat}


\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\Ruble{\stackengine{.67ex}{%
  \stackengine{.48ex}{\textsf{P}}{\rule{.8ex}{.12ex}\kern.6ex}{O}{r}{F}{F}{L}%
  }{\rule{.8ex}{.12ex}\kern.6ex}{O}{r}{F}{F}{L}\kern-.1ex}



\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcalligra}{T1}{calligra}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{calligra}{m}{n}{<->s*[2.2]callig15}{}
\newcommand{\scriptr}{\mathcalligra{r}\,}
\newcommand{\boldscriptr}{\pmb{\mathcalligra{r}}\,}
\newcommand{\quotebox}[1]{\begin{center}\fcolorbox{white}{blue!15!gray!15}{\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}\vspace{10pt}\center\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}{\space\Huge``}{#1}{\hspace{1.5em}\break\null\Huge\hfill''}\end{minipage}\smallbreak\end{minipage}}\end{center}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\hla}[1]{{\sethlcolor{teal}\hl{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ques}[1]{{\sethlcolor{pink}\hl{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tar}[1]{{\textcolor{red}{#1}}}

\newcommand{\mc}[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{m}{#2}}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}

\newcolumntype{a}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}m}
\newcolumntype{b}{>{\columncolor{white}}m}

\colorlet{lgra}{lightgray!60}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\hlg}[1]{{\sethlcolor{lgra}\hl{#1}}}




\usetikzlibrary{shapes,decorations,arrows,calc,arrows.meta,fit,positioning}
\tikzset{
    -Latex,auto,node distance =1 cm and 1 cm,semithick,
    state/.style ={ellipse, draw, minimum width = 0.7 cm},
    point/.style = {circle, draw, inner sep=0.04cm,fill,node contents={}},
    bidirected/.style={Latex-Latex},
    el/.style = {inner sep=2pt, align=left, sloped}
}

\tikzstyle{mbigblock} = [rectangle, draw, text width=5cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=1em]
\tikzstyle{block}  = [rectangle, draw, text width=3.5cm, text centered, minimum height=1em]
\tikzstyle{lblock} = [rectangle, draw, text width=5cm, text centered, minimum height=1em]
\tikzstyle{rblock} = [rectangle, draw, text width=3.5cm, text centered, minimum height=1em]
\usepackage[showboxes, absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}


\small
\begin{textblock*}{11cm}(0.7cm, 1.6cm)
  \begin{minipage}[t][7.5cm][t]{10.16cm}
  \begin{textblock*}{0.67cm}(10.6cm,1.9cm)
  \vspace{0.8mm}
    \centering
     4/5
    \vspace{0.5mm}
    \end{textblock*}
   \vspace{0.8cm}
     Um Hassan felt left out from the conversation. At dinner, Riad meets another general's son, a spoiled brat, who thought you needed permission to play on his playground. Riad is introduced to the First Sura and the Five Pillars of Islam at school. He read the Sura but  didn't understand any of it, but neither did the other kids. The Presidential Election rolls around and the teacher asks everyone to tell their parents to vote for al-Assad (he won with a 100\% record). One day, Riad developed a fever and was rushed to the new town pediatrician. He recommended that the tonsils be taken out and that the operation be done in France. Abdel didn't translate this to Cl\'ementine, insiting that Syrian doctors were the best in the world. The trope of not taking money from Abdel comes into play again (\hlg{explanation?}). On the TV, Riad sees Syrian Special Forces women biting in snakes to, as Abdel asserts, ``\emph{show Israel that they weren't scared of anything}". Later that night, it is revealed that Leila was 3 months pregnant. Maha's husband and son, \ul{Ahmed}, suffocated the poor woman and buried her in their field. Cl\'ementine urged Abdel to throw the murderers in jail. The boys go to  
   \begin{textblock*}{4.9cm}(6.45cm, 8.6cm)
   \vspace{0.6mm}
   The Arab of the Future, 1984-85.04
    \vspace{0.6mm}
  \end{textblock*}
  \end{minipage}
\end{textblock*}
\begin{textblock*}{11cm}(0.7cm, 9.5cm)
  \begin{minipage}[t][7.5cm][t]{10.16cm}
   \begin{textblock*}{0.67cm}(10.7cm,9.8cm)
  \vspace{0.8mm}
    \centering
     5/5
     \vspace{0.5mm}
    \end{textblock*}
   \vspace{0.8cm}
        France with their mother. While there, they visit the Euromarch\'e Superstore in Longeaux. The Betamax was 300 Francs here (approximately \$50, opposed to the \$250-\$350 Abdel paid back in Homs). Riad's grandmother taught him how to catch sand eels, periwinkles, mussels, chinese hats, and crabs. She also shows him a Nazi bunker on the beach. \hlg{Looks like she has some unresolved issues from the occupation.} They go skiing at La Giettaz. Riad isn't very successful in  the sport. Back in Syria, Abdel tells a horror story about hyenas. During the tail end of winter, the school was flooded and closed. After the vacation, Riad got a new teacher, who was pretty much the same sadist, with new methods. Omar never came back to school. Cl\'ementine started teaching Riad French. Funnily, one day, Riad scared Anas by grabbing a crab from the spring. During the summer holidays, the family went to Lakatia and we witness a sad episode involving the pool inflatable man. The trees in Abdel's field were growing and on the walk back home, they saw Mahas's ex-husband (who was released from the prison after only 3 months, based on `honor' considerations).  
    \begin{textblock*}{4.9cm}(6.45cm, 16.4cm)
   \vspace{0.6mm}
    The Arab of the Future. 1984-85.05
    \vspace{0.6mm}
  \end{textblock*}
  \end{minipage}
\end{textblock*}

\begin{textblock*}{11cm}(0.7cm, 17.5cm)
  \begin{minipage}[t][7.5cm][t]{10.16cm}
  \begin{textblock*}{0.67cm}(10.7cm,17.9cm)
  \vspace{0.8mm}
    \centering
     1/5
     \vspace{0.4mm}
    \end{textblock*}
   \vspace{0.8cm}
   \noindent
   Riad is about to star school and Abdel buys him his uniform and a book bag (both made of cheap plastic material). Abdel also pressures him to study hard to become a doctor. The next morning, Riad walks to school with his dad but Abdel doesn't want to be seen with him (\ques{is this some Arab unspoken rule?}). He is late on his first day and doesn't have a patriotic collar and cap, both required elements on the uniform. He encounters the cruelty of the system, and the students spend the rest of the day singing the national anthem, \emph{Hum\=at ad-Diy\=ar}. He also makes friends with \ul{Saleem} and \ul{Omar}. Anas beats up Riad, but in turn gets beaten up by a teacher. When Riad doesn't have the cap and the collar the next day, he gets caned by the teacher, even with Abdel's Damascus University-stamped paper. The Sattoufs go to visit \ul{Maha}, Abdel's half-sister. We are also introduced to \ul{Leila}, a cross-eyed, divorced cousin. She invites Riad to watch how \emph{saktoura} is made (most likely referring to \emph{Asheh}, the dish is too local to be found online). Interestingly, Abdel's father was 90 years-old when he was born. Leila takes an interest in Riad's art and transforms Pompidou into Hafez 
   \begin{textblock*}{4.9cm}(6.45cm, 24.4cm)
   \vspace{0.6mm}
    The Arab of the Future. 1984-85.01
    \vspace{0.6mm}
  \end{textblock*}
  \end{minipage}
\end{textblock*}


\begin{textblock*}{7.5cm}(12.5cm, 1.5cm)
\begin{flushright}
    \rotatebox{90}{
  \begin{minipage}[t][10.16cm][t]{10.20cm}
  \begin{textblock*}{0.5cm}(12.8cm,1.9cm)
     \rotatebox{90}{\vspace{0.1mm} 2/5 \vspace{0.1mm}}
    \end{textblock*}
   \vspace{0.8cm}
   \noindent
    al-Assad. She also teaches him the use of perspective. There are no toilets in the school + the teacher seems like an anti-semite, but considers Paris to be a beautiful city. Cl\'ementine is depressed with her life, but cooks quite a bit of Syrian food. Wael and Mohamed, the cousins take Riad to Madman's field, a plot of land belonging to \ul{Abu Ahmed}. Abu was convinced that there was some buried treasure as Ter Maaleh was a Roman settlement before becoming an Arab village. He never finds any treasure, but in the panels, we see remnants of Roman pottery (\hlg{which is considered worthless?}). Riad learns some aspects of Syrian social dynamics (a more demeaning middle finger gesture + proper behavior for Muslim women). Abdel shows his plans for a mansion and explains how he couldn't eat French food at first, thinking that it was poisoned (the fear was justified when he puked after eating a huge amount of strawberry yogurt). One day, the Sattoufs are invited to the general's house. Riad pointed a gun at the general's son's head and the kid just flips out (\hlg{still no idea why. Some weird power move?}). Turns out \ul{Um Hassan} has 9 lbs of gold. It's winter and Riad teaches us Arabic alphabet.   
    \begin{textblock*}{0.4cm}(19.48cm, 1.8cm)
   \rotatebox{90}{\vspace{0.1mm}
    The Arab of the Future. 1984-85.02
    \vspace{0.1mm}}
  \end{textblock*}
  \end{minipage}}
\end{flushright}
\end{textblock*}


\begin{textblock*}{7.5cm}(12.5cm, 13.5cm)
\begin{flushright}
    \rotatebox{90}{
  \begin{minipage}[t][10.16cm][t]{10.20cm}
  \begin{textblock*}{0.5cm}(12.8cm,13.9cm)
     \rotatebox{90}{\vspace{0.1mm} 3/5 \vspace{0.1mm}}
    \end{textblock*}
   \vspace{0.8cm}
   \noindent
    The teacher had a strange level of hatred towards kids who smelled bad, maybe because she always smelled of Roses. Abdel takes Riad hunting with a double-barreled shotgun. There were a bunch of sparrows sitting on a fence. Bang! and dinner: lots of pulverized sparrows. There wasn't a lot of meat. The teacher had asked the children to take a shower on Friday. As Riad was going to school, he fell inside a large puddle and got absolutely dirty. Sure enough, he was caned by the teacher. Abdel told Riad about the wil-o-the-wisps and why he should avoid visiting cemeteries. We also learn about Muslim perspectives on afterlife. In Syria, officially imported items were slapped with taxes up to 600\%. So, the smugglers went to Lebanon and the sold the goods on the black market. Abdel buys a Sony Betamax, a gas oven, a washing machine, some pat\'e and orange juice. \ul{Abu Hassan} had invited the Sattoufs to spend Christmas in Palmyra. A tour of the old city followed and \ul{Queen Zenobia} was mentioned (Abdel says  that she was a slut, ``\emph{like all Italian women}"). Along with another family, they went to the Meridien Hotel. The new general's wife was pretty good in English and
    \begin{textblock*}{0.4cm}(19.5cm, 13.8cm)
   \rotatebox{90}{\vspace{0.1mm}
    The Arab of the Future. 1984-85.03
    \vspace{0.1mm}}
  \end{textblock*}
  \end{minipage}}
\end{flushright}
\end{textblock*}

 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scontents

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Are you sure that you need all theses packages? For example, `lipsum` and `blindtext` produce dummy texts for testing. `chemformula` is for chemistry, probably useless for flashcards for a book. They are many like that. It's generally preferable to load only the packages you really use.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `textpos` package to place absolute boxes on the page. But the effective content of the page remains empty. So `\clearpage` has no effect.

Add invisible content, outside the `textblock*`:

```tex
\mbox{}
\clearpage
\mbox{}
```

Full example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showboxes, absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{textblock*}{11cm}(0.7cm, 1.6cm)
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{textblock*}

\mbox{}
\clearpage
\mbox{}

\begin{textblock*}{11cm}(0.7cm, 1.6cm)
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{textblock*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found your code very complicated, and maybe you can do better and simpler with the [tcolorbox](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbo) package.

For example:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\DeclareTColorBox{flashcard}{ O{} }
{
  colback=white,
  sharp corners,
  before upper={\hfill{\bfseries\sffamily\thetcbrasternum/5}\medskip\par},
  lower separated=false,
  halign lower=right,
  valign lower=bottom,
  fontupper=\footnotesize,
  fontlower=\small\itshape,
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbraster}
  [
    raster height=\textheight,
    raster rows=3,
    raster columns=2,
    raster equal height
  ]
  %% #1
  \begin{flashcard}

    Riad is about to star school and Abdel buys him his uniform and a book bag (both
    made of cheap plastic material). Abdel also pressures him to study hard to
    become a doctor. The next morning, Riad walks to school with his dad but Abdel
    doesn't want to be seen with him (is this some Arab unspoken rule?).
    He is late on his first day and doesn't have a patriotic collar and cap, both
    required elements on the uniform. He encounters the cruelty of the system, and
    the students spend the rest of the day singing the national anthem,
    \emph{Hum\=at ad-Diy\=ar}. He also makes friends with Saleem and Omar.
    Anas beats up Riad, but in turn gets beaten up by a teacher. When Riad doesn't
    have the cap and the collar the next day, he gets caned by the teacher, even
    with Abdel's Damascus University-stamped paper. The Sattoufs go to visit
    Maha, Abdel's half-sister. We are also introduced to Leila,
    a cross-eyed, divorced cousin. She invites Riad to watch how \emph{saktoura} is
    made (most likely referring to \emph{Asheh}, the dish is too local to be found
    online). Interestingly, Abdel's father was 90 years-old when he was born.
    Leila takes an interest in Riad's art and transforms Pompidou into Hafez

    \tcblower

    The Arab of the Future. 1984-85.01

  \end{flashcard}
  %% #2
  \begin{flashcard}

    al-Assad. She also teaches him the use of perspective. There are no toilets in
    the school + the teacher seems like an anti-semite, but considers Paris to be
    a beautiful city. Cl\'ementine is depressed with her life, but cooks quite
    a bit of Syrian food. Wael and Mohamed, the cousins take Riad to Madman's
    field, a plot of land belonging to Abu Ahmed. Abu was convinced that there was
    some buried treasure as Ter Maaleh was a Roman settlement before becoming an
    Arab village. He never finds any treasure, but in the panels, we see remnants
    of Roman pottery (which is considered worthless?). Riad learns some aspects of
    Syrian social dynamics (a more demeaning middle finger gesture + proper
    behavior for Muslim women). Abdel shows his plans for a mansion and explains
    how he couldn't eat French food at first, thinking that it was poisoned (the
    fear was justified when he puked after eating a huge amount of strawberry
    yogurt). One day, the Sattoufs are invited to the general's house.
    Riad pointed a gun at the general's son's head and the kid just flips out
    (still no idea why. Some weird power move?). Turns out Um Hassan has 9 lbs of
    gold. It's winter and Riad teaches us Arabic alphabet.

    \tcblower

    The Arab of the Future. 1984-85.02

  \end{flashcard}
  %% #
  \begin{flashcard}

    The teacher had a strange level of hatred towards kids who smelled bad, maybe
    because she always smelled of Roses. Abdel takes Riad hunting with
    a double-barreled shotgun. There were a bunch of sparrows sitting on a fence.
    Bang! and dinner: lots of pulverized sparrows. There wasn't a lot of meat.
    The teacher had asked the children to take a shower on Friday. As Riad was
    going to school, he fell inside a large puddle and got absolutely dirty.
    Sure enough, he was caned by the teacher. Abdel told Riad about the
    wil-o-the-wisps and why he should avoid visiting cemeteries. We also learn
    about Muslim perspectives on afterlife. In Syria, officially imported items
    were slapped with taxes up to 600\%. So, the smugglers went to Lebanon and the
    sold the goods on the black market. Abdel buys a Sony Betamax, a gas oven,
    a washing machine, some pat\'e and orange juice. Abu Hassan had invited the
    Sattoufs to spend Christmas in Palmyra. A tour of the old city followed and
    Queen Zenobia was mentioned (Abdel says that she was a slut, ``\emph{like all
      Italian women}"). Along with another family, they went to the Meridien
    Hotel. The new general's wife was pretty good in English and

    \tcblower

    The Arab of the Future. 1984-85.03

  \end{flashcard}
  %% #4
  \begin{flashcard}

    Um Hassan felt left out from the conversation. At dinner, Riad meets another
    general's son, a spoiled brat, who thought you needed permission to play on
    his playground. Riad is introduced to the First Sura and the Five Pillars of
    Islam at school. He read the Sura but didn't understand any of it, but neither
    did the other kids. The Presidential Election rolls around and the teacher
    asks everyone to tell their parents to vote for al-Assad (he won with a 100\%
    record). One day, Riad developed a fever and was rushed to the new town
    pediatrician. He recommended that the tonsils be taken out and that the
    operation be done in France. Abdel didn't translate this to Cl\'ementine,
    insiting that Syrian doctors were the best in the world. The trope of not
    taking money from Abdel comes into play again (explanation?). On the TV, Riad
    sees Syrian Special Forces women biting in snakes to, as Abdel asserts,
    ``\emph{show Israel that they weren't scared of anything}". Later that night,
    it is revealed that Leila was 3 months pregnant. Maha's husband and son,
    Ahmed, suffocated the poor woman and buried her in their field. Cl\'ementine
    urged Abdel to throw the murderers in jail. The boys go to

    \tcblower

    The Arab of the Future, 1984-85.04

  \end{flashcard}
  %% #5
  \begin{flashcard}

    France with their mother. While there, they visit the Euromarch\'e Superstore
    in Longeaux. The Betamax was 300 Francs here (approximately \$50, opposed to
    the \$250-\$350 Abdel paid back in Homs). Riad's grandmother taught him how
    to catch sand eels, periwinkles, mussels, chinese hats, and crabs. She also
    shows him a Nazi bunker on the beach. Looks like she has some unresolved
    issues from the occupation. They go skiing at La Giettaz. Riad isn't very
    successful in the sport. Back in Syria, Abdel tells a horror story about
    hyenas. During the tail end of winter, the school was flooded and closed.
    After the vacation, Riad got a new teacher, who was pretty much the same
    sadist, with new methods. Omar never came back to school. Cl\'ementine
    started teaching Riad French. Funnily, one day, Riad scared Anas by grabbing
    a crab from the spring. During the summer holidays, the family went to
    Lakatia and we witness a sad episode involving the pool inflatable man.
    The trees in Abdel's field were growing and on the walk back home, they saw
    Mahas's ex-husband (who was released from the prison after only 3 months,
    based on `honor' considerations).

    \tcblower

    The Arab of the Future. 1984-85.05

  \end{flashcard}
\end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

[image: alternative with tcolorbox]